# Cannot output array from http get url success function onto the html

Tags: angularjs, controller

I am trying to output the result from the success function as following, but am having no luck. The code does return values for UpcomingEvents and if I output that to the html, it works, but when I am passing it onto the returnlist, it does not work.

```
    $scope.Events = {}
    $scope.returnlist = {};
    var PriorID = 67;
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;

    //I am calling http get url function which is working fine.
       .success(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        $scope.Events = response;
        //I am able to display Events[0].ID in html.

        if ($scope.Events[0].ID == PriorID)
        //The condition holds true, so it will go inside the loop. I have  
         confirmed that with a debugger.
        {
            newID = $scope.Events[0].ID;
            newname = $scope.Events[0].Title;
            $scope.returnlist[0] = [{ ID: newID, Name: newname }];
            $scope.returnlist[1] = [{ ID: newID, Name: newname }];
            //through debugger breakpoints, I have found that returnlist is  
            getting the correct values. 

        }

    })
```

Everything works well until I try to display the values in my html. I am trying it like this.

```
                {{returnlist[0].ID}}
```

I have even tried it like this:

```
             <tr ng-repeat="data in returnlist">
              <td>returnlist.ID</td>
```

but no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you define `$scope.returnlist = {};` which is an object not an array.

Then, when you add item you assign an array not an item of array:

```
$scope.returnlist[0] = [{ ID: newID, Name: newname }];
```

So your final returnlist will look like:

```
{0: [{ ID: newID, Name: newname }], 1:[{ ID: newID, Name: newname }],...}
```

an object with array value, so when you do $scope.returnlist[0].ID you will get undefined.

The right way is:

```
$scope.returnlist = [];//an array

//in the loop now:
$scope.returnlist[0] = { ID: newID, Name: newname };//an item not an array
```